# Is it possible to use base class member in a union in derived class?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

```
class Impl{
        char c[32];
};


typedef struct X{
        int u;
        int v;
        int w;
        int x;
}X ;

class A{
        public:
        int  a;
        int  b;
        Impl c;
        int  d;

};

class B : public A{
        public:
        union U{
                using A::c;
                X z;
        }ba ;
        int bb;
};
```

**The requirement is to remap some bytes of the base class in its client class.**

I get **error: type ‘A’ is not a base type for type B::U**.

I know the alternative solution would be to simply cast `A::c` as `struct X` - just thought this kind of solution would look elegant.

Comment: The error is pretty clear: `U` does not derive from `A`. Why would you expect it to know about `A`'s members?

Comment: As a sidenote, casting `A::c` to a `struct X` is not possible. And casting a `A::c`'s address to `X *` is undefined behavior if you do anything with the result of such cast.

Comment: Thanks, is there any other solution to the problem - such that I could create a union to be able to remap a base class member?

Comment: Barring the special case of `char` arrays, no. Even outside of any class, such thing is undefined. You may re-use the *storage*, and you might even be able to access objects if you are very careful, with some uses of `std::launder`. But I do not really see why you would want to achieve that, so I suspect the whole question could be an XY problem.

Comment: @spectras : Thanks for the concern. The question contains both, actual problem and my solution, which obviously did not work and hence this question.

Comment: maybe "requirement is to remap some bytes of the base class in its client class" is already part of the Y, your solution to some unknown X. Why do you need that?

Comment: @idclev463035818 : We have a hierarchy where class A is inherited by B already existing in our code base. The problem started because, now we wanted say 64 bytes of additional reserve space in A, but the client class B should have the ability to interpret the same bytes differently. Something like header which is different for different clients. B could be anything else as well, but needs to use the same bytes.

Comment: For a derived class to hijack the contents of a member of the base class and use the bytes in a completely different way sounds like a really bad idea (given that the base class made no provision for anyone doing something like this). Why would you want to do that?

Comment: What you told the compiler was that after it finishes defining `A`, you want to extend class `A` to class `B` by adding memory for a member `ba` and another member `bb`. By definition, for each object of type `B` the compiler has to map those members to memory outside of the memory it used for the instance of base class `A`. There will not be a way to add a new member called `ba` but tell the compiler it's really the member `c` in the base class.

Comment: Maybe you can do something in `B` with a `reinterpret_cast` in order to misuse `A::c` in whatever way you want.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have a fundamental misunderstanding of what types defined within other types are.

In some languages, when you declare a type within another type, instances of that child-type have access to its parent's state.  This isn't the case in C++.

```
union U{
  using A::c;
  X z;
};
U ba;
```

this is just another type.  You can do this:

```
int main() {
   B::U u;
}
```

and the `u` instance isn't embedded within an instance of `B` (nor `A`).

What more, `X` and `Impl` are unrelated types.  "Treating memory as" unions isn't valid C++; it is a hack that a lot of people use, but it isn't actually supported by the C++ standard.

In C++, objects are of one type or another, they cannot be accessed as either except in extremely limited ways, and `union` doesn't let you treat a struct of ints as a struct containing an array of chars.

Take this:

```
union bob {
  Impl impl;
  X x;
};
```

there is no legal way in C++ to store an `X` in `bob`, then access it via the `impl` member.

You can access the bytes of an `X`, but you cannot do it through a `union`.  `union` simply let you have an area of storage that can be either type A or type B.  Barring some extremely narrow circumstances involving structure prefixes, you cannot access the data in a union through any means except the exact type that the union currently holds.

Many compilers permit this technique to a greater or lesser extent, but any solution there is going to be compiler specific and not a general C++ solution.

```
template<class T, class U>
T make_byte_copy( U const& u ) {
  static_assert( sizeof(T)<=sizeof(U) );
  static_assert( is_trivially_copyable<T>{} );
  static_assert( is_trivially_copyable<U>{} );
  T t;
  std::memcpy( std::addressof(t), std::addressof(u), sizeof(T) );
  return t;
}

X getX() const {
  return make_byte_copy<X>(c);
}
void setX(X const& in) const {
  c = make_byte_copy<impl>(in);
}
```

this is a rough sketch of how you can read bytes from one type to another.  I'd advise asking a SO question on the topic, as I may have errors above, but a technique like the above is going to work.

---

Another approach involves placement new.  You can create an `X` within the memory of `Impl`.

This is quite tricky to do without invoking undefined behaviour.  There are lots of ways to do it that seem to work but violate the standard.

If you want this approach, it would look roughly like:

```
 struct base {
   std::array<char, 24> data;
 };
 struct bob {int x,y,z;};
 struct derived:base {
   derived(){
     static_assert(sizeof(bob)<=sizeof(data));
     static_assert(alignof(bob)<=alignof(data));
      ::new((void*)&data) bob{1,2,3};
    }
    ~derived(){ x()->~bob(); }
    bob& x()&{ return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<bob*>(&data)); }
    bob const& x() const&{ return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<bob const*>(&data)); }
  };
```

but again, I plausibly made some mistakes.  If you want to usr this route ask a narrow question about how to do this right.